# Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::ci_form_validation() while extending the class in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to add some custom validation functions for my project. I'm using CI 2.0.2. I followed all the steps described at [www.michaelwales.com/2010/02/basic-pattern-matching-form-validation-in-codeigniter/](http://www.michaelwales.com/2010/02/basic-pattern-matching-form-validation-in-codeigniter/)

I created a class in application\libraries as follows -

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed.');
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

     public function MY_Form_validation() {
        parent::__construct();
      }

             function valid_us_zip()
            {...........}
}//class ends
```

I added rule to my application\config\form_validation.php as follows -

```
   $config = array(
       'login/sign_up_process' => array(
           array(
                 'field' => 'txt_username_signup',
                 'label' => 'Username',
                 'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean|prep_for_form'
                                     ),
           array(
                 'field' => 'txt_zip_signup',
                 'label' => 'Zip',
                 'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_us_zip|xss_clean|prep_for_form'
                                     )                                           

                                )
           );
```

In my controller function I've added code as -

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
echo "Error ::".$this->form_validation->run();
```

My validation was working before extending form validation class, but now it does not give any error even though I submit empty form. I'm not able to fix this :(

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I got it working :)

All the steps I explained in my question are correct. In CI2+, as **swatkins** has mentioned we are to keep the extended core class files in application/core and library files in application/library.

I kept my extended MY_Form_validation.php in application/library and found that the $config was not passed to the constructor of parent. I edited it as -

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed.');
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

 public function MY_Form_validation($config) {
    parent::__construct($config);
  }

         function valid_us_zip()
        {...........}
}//class ends
```

And tested it. My custom function was called and I received the error message also. I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: On this page http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html it states that when you extend a class you put it in 'core'. As you seem to be suggesting, and as seems to be the case having tried it, MY_Form_validation in fact goes in the libraries folder.. why is the manual wrong?:P

Answer (score 0):

In CI2+, you need to put these new libraries that extend the core in the `core` folder, not in `libraries`.

Comment: If I move MY_Form_validation to core, it works but my extended class in not being loaded. If I keep it on library folder my extended class is loaded but then nothing happens... :(

Comment: Take a look at this forum here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/148607/#722895 -- it seems you have to pass the `$config` variable to your constructor and the parent constructor in your extending class. Also, make sure that you either autoload or manually load the form validation class.

Answer (score 0):

Make file name in your application/library directory:
**MY_Form_validation.php**

then in your class

Code:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation

{
 function My_Form_validation()
   {
       parent::__construct();
   }

}
```